# opencart 2.3.0.2 latest products without special prices

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module, opencart2.3

I want, in the latest module to be able to show only the products that don't have special price!
in `model/catalog/product.php` I have modified `getLatestProducts()` function from

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {

                $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);

        }
```

with

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
$queryCheckSpecial = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM ". DB_PREFIX ."product_special WHERE product_id =".$result['product_id']);
    if (!$queryCheckSpecial->row){
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }else{
        continue;
        }
    }
```

but it's not working! 
What I'm doing wrong?
any help will be apreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

```
catalog\controller\extension\module\latest.php
```

**Find:**

```
'sort'  => 'p.date_added',
```

**Add after:**

```
'ignore_special'  => 1,
```

**Edit:**

```
catalog\model\catalog\product.php
```

**Find** (first match):

```
if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
```

**Add before:**

```
if (!empty($data['ignore_special'])) {
    $sql .= " AND (SELECT price FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_special ps WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id AND ps.customer_group_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_customer_group_id') . "' AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) IS NULL";
}
```

Then clear your caches.

Answer (score 0):

simply update:

> **this:**

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
$queryCheckSpecial = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM ". DB_PREFIX ."product_special WHERE product_id =".$result['product_id']);
    if (!$queryCheckSpecial->row){
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }else{
        continue;
        }
    }
}
```

> **with:**

```
foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
    $product_info = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    if (!$product_info['special']){
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = 
    }
}
```

**Also don't forget to clear cache before testing.**

Answer (score 0):

@digicart
I've done in catalog\controller\extension\module\latest.php

```
'ignore_special'  => 1,
```

in catalog\model\catalog\product.php

```
if (!empty($data['ignore_special']) &&  empty($data['filter_category_id'])){

            $this->log->debug('dsadsa');

            $queryCheckSpecial = $this->db->query("SELECT product_id FROM ". DB_PREFIX ."product_special WHERE product_id =".$result['product_id']);
            if (!$queryCheckSpecial->row){

                $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);

            }else{
                continue;

           }
```

at the end of getproducts()

And it's working on latest page! Problem is that in category page, somehow the ignore special field is present, and i don't know why !